# connect class with root view controller (UINavigationController)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Here is my Project: [Link](http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/6895/o06t.png)

I want to connect the selected View with the class ViewController. But it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Connect in what way? You need to give more information.

Comment: You can see it on the top right. I want to connect it there with the class ViewController, but it doesn't work.

Comment: From the image you posted they look pretty connected. Can you maybe explain in what way you want to connect them? What is the purpose of connecting them. You need to post as much information as possible so people can help you, we don't know what you are build or what you want to do.

Comment: I want to connect the selected view (that with a blue border) here: http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/6145/0ew6.png with the class View Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a UITableViewController. So make your ViewController extending UITableViewController.
or
drag and drop a UIViewController and write the class.

Go to ViewController.h

It should show :`@interface ViewController : UIViewController`

Make it : `@interface ViewController : UITableViewController`

Once you have made this change you will be able to select 'ViewController' in interface builder as the Class.

Comment: How can I do that? (I'm a beginner)

Answer (score 0):

Change the class to ViewController (That is the class name of view controller in the image you posted.)

[Link you posted of class](http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/6145/0ew6.png)

Comment: I did that, but I can only select UITableViewController. http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/695/skkm.png

Comment: You view controller is it a subclass of UITableViewController or a subclass of UIViewController? You can manually type ViewController in there but if the classes don't match your app will probably crash.

Comment: How can I change the subclass of the ViewController?

Comment: Please see Samkit Jain's answer. He explains how to subclass.